# Why the Opacity[] looks not work on my PC?

Tags: opacity

Help: Why the Opacity[] looks as a failure when I run it on my PC? How to do? The following figure is a code line in the Help. The left side is the result, and the transparency effect is not obvious, while the right side is the original picture with obvious transparency effect in the Help.

[image]

The transparency effect is also obvious when I run it on Wolfram Cloud. Why? please help me. Than you.

Comment: Please try this and report if any of the three plots produced look OK: `Table[Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5], 
  BaseStyle -> 
   RenderingOptions -> {"Graphics3DRenderingEngine" -> 
      method}], {method, {"HardwareDepthPeeling", "BSPTree", "Software"}}]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thank you very much. The second works. My notebook is an old machine maybe without any picture hardware. And How can I set my Mathematica? Once more thank you.

Comment: Evaluating this will set the option to persist between sessions: `SetOptions[$FrontEnd, 
 RenderingOptions -> {"Graphics3DRenderingEngine" -> "BSPTree"}]`  Or you can also use the **Option Inspector**.

Comment: Your suggestion is totally effective! Thank you very much again.

Comment: Just as an FYI, Graphics3DRenderingEngine was deprecated in 11.3 (maybe earlier, I don't have it installed at the moment).  The modern equivalent is 3DRenderingMethod.

Comment: @ihojnicki I am still using version 10.1 and I wasn't aware of that.  Thanks for the note.